# rake aborted! cannot load such file -- net/telnet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, telnet, cartodb

I am installing cartoDB in ubuntu using this [procedure](http://cartodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#editor) . When I initialize the metadatabase using the following command

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake db:create
```

I get an error saying

```
rake aborted! cannot load such file -- net/telnet
```

The stack trace

> /home/ubuntu/cartodb/lib/varnish/lib/cartodb-varnish.rb:1:in `require'
>   /home/ubuntu/cartodb/lib/varnish/lib/cartodb-varnish.rb:1:in`' /home/ubuntu/cartodb/config/application.rb:189:in
>   `require' /home/ubuntu/cartodb/config/application.rb:189:in`' /home/ubuntu/cartodb/Rakefile:3:in `require'
>   /home/ubuntu/cartodb/Rakefile:3:in`'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in
>   `load'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in`
>   load_rakefile'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in
>   `raw_load_rakefile'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in`
>   block in load_rakefile'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in
>   `standard_exception_handling'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in`
>   load_rakefile'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in
>   `block in run'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in`
>   standard_exception_handling'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in
>   `run' /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in`
>   ' /usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
>   /usr/local/bin/rake:23:in`'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in
>   `load'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in`
>   kernel_load'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:24:in
>   `run'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:304:in`
>   exec'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in
>   `run'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in`
>   invoke_command'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in
>   `dispatch'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in`
>   start'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in
>   `start'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/exe/bundle:27:in`
>   block in '
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:98:in
>   `with_friendly_errors'
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/exe/bundle:19:in`
>   ' /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
>   /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in`'

What could be the problem. I am not conversant with RoR.

Comment: ruby version is 2.3.1

Comment: According to [documentation](http://cartodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#ruby) cartoDB works best with ruby 2.2.3. Try my answer below.. might help you solve the issue

Comment: any luck solving the issue ?

Comment: Yeah, Manged to solve this error. But another  appeared

Comment: whats the new error ?

Comment: 'Error connecting to Redis databases: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)'

.The stack trace - http://pastebin.com/raw/LUfBx24E

.  thanks in advance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122899/discussion-between-tony-vincent-and-1088).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the [`Gemfile`](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/blob/c089b5e3d1af6f7695983e7fcd27e891450aacb4/Gemfile)
and add the following line (just below line 35 `gem 'net-ldap', '0.11'`)

```
gem install 'net-telnet'
```

run

```
$ bundle
```